# Getting KeyError using Pandas when accessing .csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, finance

For some reason pandas is throwing an error when looking through some .csv stock data I have. Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: 'Date'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./python-for-finance-7.py", line 75, in 
>       compile_data()
>     File "./python-for-finance-7.py", line 59, in compile_data
>       df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", >line 3909, in set_index
>       level = frame[col]._values
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", >line 2688, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", >line 2695, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site->packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc>    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: 'Date'

to this code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os 
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests

def compile_data():
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle","rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for count,ticker in enumerate(tickers):
        df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker), 
delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")

        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

        df.rename(columns = {'Adj Close':ticker}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['High','Low','Open','Close','Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

        print(count)

    print(main_df.head())
    main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')

compile_data()
```

The data in the CSV files is arranged like this:

```
Date         High   Low  Open   Close   Volume   Adj. Close

yyyy-mm-dd   $$      $$   $$      $$      $$       $$
```

I tried changing the casing of Date (ie changing Date to date) but it just moves on to throw another

> KeyError:"['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume'] not found in axis

Can someone please help??

Comment: If you add `print(df.head())` right after `df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker), 
delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")`, what is the exact output?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler It seems like there is another column at the begining simply marking numbers 0,1,2, etc.... the output is:   
    date              open      high             low         close   volume`

0  2014-01-02  122.5646  123.4081  122.1740  122.6357  3053521

1  2014-01-03  122.8488  123.3015  122.5469  122.9198  2133336

2  2014-01-06  123.1861  123.6656  122.0586  122.1918  2712055

3  2014-01-07  122.0319  122.6978  121.7478  122.2095  2525529

4  2014-01-08  122.0586  122.2983  121.0465  121.3039  3122674

Comment: Also sorry for the formatting, Im having trouble with it when writing comments

Comment: Ok I see what the issue is, in some of the csv files the column names are capitalized while in others they are not. Is there any way to define the columns as either/or uppercase/lowercase and then standardize it to all lowercase or all uppercase?

Comment: I just solved it! ended up printing the ticker at the end of each loop in order to see which tickers are the ones with lowercase instead of uppercase names. Deleted those csv files and re downloaded the data properly formatted :) thanks for your help though it gave me the idea that led me to this

Comment: glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the wrong delineator. The file is white-space delineated, not comma delineated.

Try using a whitespace delineator:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker), 
delimiter=r'\s+', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it throws this error:
    arserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker), delimiter=r'/s+', encoding = "utf-8-sig")

However when I specify the engine = 'python' I still get a KeyError date. However I think it is because the date is on column 2 with a column before it that simply counts the rows (ie 0,1,2,3,4,etc...)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have any entries when setting the index, the data frame was empty. 
It's worth checking

```
if len(df) > 0:
```

before setting the index